# A Linux Shell Script Problem

Tags: linux, string, shell, sed

I have a string separated by dot in Linux Shell,

```
$example=This.is.My.String
```

I want to

1.Add some string before the last dot, for example, I want to add "Good.Long" before the  last dot, so I get:

```
This.is.My.Goood.Long.String
```

2.Get the part after the last dot, so I will get

```
String
```

3.Turn the dot into underscore except the last dot, so I will get

```
This_is_My.String
```

If you have time, please explain a little bit, I am still learning Regular Expression.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Based on your tags, it sounds like this is specifically a sed question, right? (Except that `$example` in the first line, which makes it look perl...)

Comment: Yes,It is about sed. I havent install perl on my Linux.

Comment: Is this *really* a question about `sed`? It looks from the question that it's just about shell scripting.

Comment: I suggest for you to change the title. All threads on this site deal about "Linux Shell Script Problem" :-) .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by 'Linux Shell' so I will assume `bash`. This solution will also work in `zsh`, *etcetera*:

```
example=This.is.My.String
before_last_dot=${example%.*}
after_last_dot=${example##*.}
echo ${before_last_dot}.Goood.Long.${after_last_dot} 
This.is.My.Goood.Long.String

echo ${before_last_dot//./_}.${after_last_dot} 
This_is_My.String
```

The interim variables `before_last_dot` and `after_last_dot` should explain my usage of the `%` and `##` operators. The `//`, I also think is self-explanatory but I'd be happy to clarify if you have any questions.

This doesn't use `sed` (or even regular expressions), but `bash`'s inbuilt parameter substitution. I prefer to stick to just one language per script, with as few forks as possible :-)

Comment: I didn't know bash is so powerful! This answer is an eye-opener for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help. "Thanks a lot!" is usually expressed on StackOverflow as an up-vote or an accepted answer (for the one that helped you solve your problem).

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution

1. Two versions of this, too:

   - Complex: `sed 's/\(.*\)\([.][^.]*$\)/\1.Goood.Long\2/'`
   - Simple: `sed 's/.*\./&Goood.Long./'` - thanks [Dennis Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26428/dennis-williamson)
2. What do you want?

   - Complex: `sed 's/.*[.]\([^.]*\)$/\1/'`
   - Simpler: `sed 's/.*\.//'` - thanks, [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman).
3. `sed 's/\([^.]*\)[.]\([^.]*[.]\)/\1_\2/g'`

With 3, you probably need to run the substitute (in its entirety) at least twice, in general.

#### Explanation

Remember, in `sed`, the notation `\(...\)` is a 'capture' that can be referenced as '`\1`' or similar in the replacement text.

1. Capture everything up to a string starting with a dot followed by a sequence of non-dots (which you also capture); replace by what came before the last dot, the new material, and the last dot and what came after it.
2. Ignore everything up to the last dot followed by a capture of a sequence of non-dots; replace with the capture only.
3. Find and capture a sequence of non-dots, a dot (not captured), followed by a sequence of non-dots and a dot; replace the first dot with an underscore.  This is done globally, but the second and subsequent matches won't touch anything already matched.  Therefore, I think you need ceil(log<sub>2</sub>N) passes, where N is the number of dots to be replaced.  One pass deals with 1 dot to replace; two passes deals with 2 or 3; three passes deals with 4-7, and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot!:)If u could explain a little bit then it will be perfect.

Comment: Your #2 can be simpler: `sed 's/^.*\.//'`

Comment: @Glenn: err...yes - that's what comes of fitting it in around a con-call that you're supposed to paying attention to.

Comment: Similarly, #1 can be simplified to: `sed 's/\(.*\.\)/\1Goood.Long./'`

Comment: And I see that I missed the opportunity for further simplification using `&`!

Comment: @Dennis: many eyes make for shallow bugs - or all code, even one-liners, can benefit from constructive code review.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Other users have given good answers for #1 and #2. There are some disadvantages to some of the answers for #3. In one case, you have to run the substitution twice. In another, if your string has other underscores they might get clobbered. This command works in one go and only affects dots:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\./\1\n./;h;s/[^\n]*\n//;x;s/\n.*//;s/\./_/g;G;s/\n//'
```

1. It splits the line before the last dot by inserting a newline and copies the result into hold space:

   ```
   s/\(.*\)\./\1\n./;h
   ```
2. removes everything up to and including the newline from the copy in pattern space and swaps hold space and pattern space:

   ```
   s/[^\n]*\n//;x
   ```
3. removes everything after and including the newline from the copy that's now in pattern space

   ```
   s/\n.*//
   ```
4. changes all dots into underscores in the copy in pattern space and appends hold space onto the end of pattern space

   ```
   s/\./_/g;G
   ```
5. removes the newline that the append operation adds

   ```
   s/\n//
   ```

Then the `sed` script is finished and the pattern space is output.

At the end of each numbered step (some consist of two actual steps):

Step        Pattern Space                 Hold Space

1. This.is.My`\n`.String       This.is.My`\n`.String
2. This.is.My`\n`.String       .String
3. This.is.My                        .String
4. This_is_My`\n`.String     .String
5. This_is_My.String            .String

Comment: Nice work; you must have had more time to think about it than I did.

Comment: @Jonathan: Possibly, but it's a common pattern in `sed` - "divide and conquer". Quite similar to Johnysweb's Bash answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version that uses Bash's regex matching (Bash 3.2 or greater).

```
[[ $example =~ ^(.*)\.(.*)$ ]]
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]//./_}.${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
```

Here's a Bash version that uses `IFS` (Internal Field Separator).

```
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=.
array=($e)                    # *   split the string at each dot
lastword=${array[@]: -1}
unset "array[${#array}-1]"    # *
IFS=_
echo "${array[*]}.$lastword"  #     The asterisk as a subscript when inside quotes causes IFS (an underscore in this case) to be inserted between each element of the array
IFS=$saveIFS
```

* use `declare -p array` after these steps to see what the array looks like.

Comment: +1 for showing there're more than one way to skin a cat. Some ways are more readable than others, mind.

Answer (score 2):

1.

```
$ echo 'This.is.my.string' | sed 's}[^\.][^\.]*$}Good Long.&}'
This.is.my.Good Long.string
```

before: a dot, then no dot until the end. after: obvious, & is what matched the first part

2.

```
$ echo 'This.is.my.string' | sed 's}.*\.}}'
string
```

sed greedy matches, so it will extend the first closure (.*) as far as possible i.e. to the last dot.

3.

```
$ echo 'This.is.my.string' | tr . _ | sed 's/_\([^_]*\)$/\.\1/'
This_is_my.string
```

convert all dots to _, then turn the last _ to a dot.

(caveat: this will turn 'This.is.my.string_foo' to 'This_is_my_string.foo', not 'This_is_my.string_foo')

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regular expressions at all (those complex things hurt my eyes!) if you use Awk and are a little creative.

```
1. echo $example| awk -v ins="Good.long" -F . '{OFS="."; $NF = ins"."$NF;print}'
```

What this does:
-v ins="Good.long" tells awk to create a variable called 'ins' with "Good.long" as content,
-F . tells awk to use the dot as a separator for your fields for input,
-OFS tells awk to use the dot as a separator for your fields as output,
NF is the number of fields, so $NF represents the last field,
the $NF=... part replaces the last field, it appends the current last string to what you want to insert (the variable called "ins" declared earlier).

```
2. echo $example| awk -F . '{print $NF}'
```

$NF is the last field, so that's all!

```
3. echo $example| awk -F . '{OFS="_"; $(NF-1) = $(NF-1)"."$NF; NF=NF-1; print}'
```

Here we have to be creative, as Awk AFAIK doesn't allow deleting fields. Of course, we set the output field separateor to underscore.

$(NF-1) = $(NF-1)"."$NF: First, we replace the second last field with the last glued to the second last, with a dot between.
Then, we fool awk to make it think the Number of fields is equal to the number of fields minus one, hence deleting the last field!

Note you can't say $NF="", because then it would display two underscores.